# css html centering div within parent div

Tags: html, css

Why won't the green button center within the red parent div?

CSS

```
.button_green {
    background-image: url('../Images/btn_bg.jpg');
    width: 202px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
    font-family: Arial;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
   }

#col2_rightbuttons span { 
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:5 auto 0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="col2_rightbuttons" style="background-color:red;">
   <div class="button_green">
        <span>test2</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `display: block` instead of `inline-block`. Plus, no need for span inside div - just combine the two and use a single element, preferably the more semantically correct `button`.

Answer (score 2):

The shorthand declaration of `margin` takes 4 arguments moving from the top and going around clockwise. Use

```
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
```

this is the same as

```
margin-top: 0;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: auto;
```

which should centre your green button.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS3 (popular animation platform http://famo.us uses CSS3)

```
#div {
   position: absolute
   left: 50%
   top: 50%
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

`translate` uses the child's own sizing

Remember to add prefixes -webkit, -moz, -o, etc. and remember that any other `transform` property will overwrite existing `transform` property

Use JS to query select / concatenate an inline-css string, or you can just use a seperate container "shell" for other positional changes

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` and I'm not sure if you need the `display: inline-block` for the parent div it can just be `display: block`.